# Rest WCF url Routing & Web Forms Url Routing problem

Tags: asp.net, wcf, url-routing

I have a Web application where i have added a reference to a RESTful WCF.

I got the WCF url Routing to work in my webapplication by adding `Inherits="RestService.Global"` to the Web applications Global.asax.

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="RestService.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

But then i tried to create url Routing for the Web application and it does not work with the `Inherits="RestService.Global"` in the Global.asax. If i take it away it works fine. Is there a correct way to do this. Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're setting the Inherits attribute of the Global.asax for the purpose of enables WCF url Routing.  Follow [this post](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/08/21/restful-wcf-services-with-no-svc-file-and-no-config.aspx) step by step and your routing for RESTful WCF should be set up just fine.